# Can I create multiple objects in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models

The questions is really simple. I have ItemPicture model which is

```
class ItemPicture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/static/shop/images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f"{self.name} id={self.pk}")

    def get_url(self):
        return self.picture.url
```

How can I create, for example, 5 objects at once with django admin? I should be able to upload 5 photos and give them 5 names.

django-bulk-admin and django-mass-edit didn't work for me

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean ? Also, why can't you just create them by code or use fixtures ?

Comment: Use django shell and then just use a for loop to do so . That's it .